# How to associate a complex observable collection (collection of collections of tuples) to a datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, bind, observablecollection

I have a class which contains a certain number of tracefiels

```
 public class TracefieldsUserClass
 {            
   public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, object, object>> TraceFieldsUser = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, object, object>>();
 }
```

here every tuple contains 3 data: TracefieldName, traceFieldType, traceFieldValue

1. TFNAME="NAME", TFTYPE="STRING", TF_VALUE="ADMINISTRATOR"
2. TFNAME="PASSWORD", TFTYPE="STRING", TF_VALUE=null
3. TFNAME="IS_ADMIN", TFTYPE="BOOL", TF_VALUE="TRUE"

   so that is a dynamic collection of data.

All those are added to a collection of collection with:

```
public class CollectionClass
    {                                  
        public ObservableCollection<TracefieldsUserClass> obcTraceFieldUsers = new ObservableCollection<TracefieldsUserClass>();
    }
    public CollectionClass Collections = new CollectionClass();

as you can see in the picture at the beginning the obcTraceFieldUsers  is properly populated:
```

[image]

Now I would like to bind it to a datagrid and, as you see in the pic, I do it through:

```
dtgUsers.ItemsSource = easyRunData.Collections.obcTraceFieldUsers;
```

but nothing appears.
I would like to have something like:

> NAME------------|---PASSWORD---|---IS_ADMIN
>
> ---
>
> Administrator---|------------------------|------TRUE
>
> User1-------------|-------123------------|------FALSE
> Thank you in advance
> Patrick

Comment: Can you please add the DataGrid (especially the Columns)?

Comment: The datagrid is filled by the databing  <DataGrid Name="dtgUsers" /> with dtgUsers.ItemsSource = easyRunData.Collections.obcTraceFieldUsers; no columns appear when the program is launched

Comment: Do you want to show all tracefields?

Comment: As a start yes please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have an `ObservableCollection` of ObservableCollections. By iterating through the ObservableCollection you pass in as `ItemsSource`, the `DataGrid` only finds `ObservableCollection`s, which it does not know how to display.

You need to reduce it to one collection, for example:

```
dtgUsers.ItemsSource = easyRunData.Collections.obcTraceFieldUsers
    .SelectMany(tracefieldsUserClass => tracefieldsUserClass.TraceFieldsUser);
```

If that solution is not feasible in your situation, there is no automatic way which allows you to show your data structure, so you'd have to create the columns manually.

Comment: Thank you I know that this is the problem but the solution is unacceptable. No other workaround around apart from manually building columns?

Comment: Maybe a `DataTemplate` could work, I'm not sure though

Comment: Please what I'd accept as a solution is the certainty that there is no automatic way to associate a datagrid to a collection of collections. By knowing so I will build columns manually. Thanks